# Azure Search Index - Access unretrievable fields in Search Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azureportal

Azure Portal provides a way to test Azure Search Index queries using the 'Search explorer' page.

If one of the fields in the index is not set as Retrievable, it won't appear in the results when retrieving data.

For debugging purposes, is there a way to force-show fields in Search explorer which are not set as Retrievable ?

Or some other way to view all fields of a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the field is not marked Retrievable, there is no way to get it.
You'll have to set `retrievable` to `true` for the field, which you can do without re-creating the index. However, this is not recommended for production indexes where presumably the existence of the non-retrievable field shouldn't be disclosed.

Comment: Edited to reflect the fact that you don't actually have to re-create the index to toggle "retrievable".

Comment: Wait what? You can? :D My bad. Can any other attributes be enabled for a column after index creation?

Comment: retrievable, synonymMaps, and searchAnalyzer can all be changed without index re-creation since they are not tied to the persistent state of the index. I thought we documented this, but now I can't seem to find it. I'll make sure it's mentioned in the API reference.

Comment: Also, to be fair, this behavior did change in March of this year, so it wasn't always possible to change retrievable (even though arguably it should have been). :)